# Bug in boost::filesystem, is this possible?

Tags: c++, boost

when I try to compile this code:

```
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    boost::filesystem3::path file_path("C:\\Users\\Art\\Desktop\\ASO.sln");
    boost::filesystem3::path new_path(file_path.begin(),file_path.end() - 1);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
C:\Users\Me\boost_path\..\..\..\boost_148\include\boost-1_48\boost\filesystem\v3\path.hpp:163: error: no matching function for call to 'convert(const boost::filesystem3::path*, const boost::filesystem3::path*, boost::filesystem3::path::string_type&, const codecvt_type&)'
```

Why? I assume there is a bug in `boost::filesystem`.

Comment: **Always** first assume the bug is in _your_ code. Occasionally, you'll be wrong, but usually that's correct.

Comment: What about just `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` instead of all those files separately?

Comment: @daknøk: Because he doesn't *want* to include everything. If he's not using `directory_iterator`, then why waste the compiler's time to include them?

Comment: @NicolBolas oh no! The build takes ten milliseconds longer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `begin()` and `end()` iterators of `boost::filesystem::path` are *not* character iterators. They are *directory* iterators; they iterate over the directories in a path. The `value_type` of these iterators are `path`s themselves, which contain the directory.

So you can't construct a `path` from another `path`'s iterators like that.

Answer (score 2):

Your second line of code has a `-1` where none is needed.  Below is the code of the ctor you're calling.

```
template <class InputIterator>
    path(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end)
    { 
      if (begin != end)
      {
        std::basic_string<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type>
          s(begin, end);
        path_traits::convert(s.c_str(), s.c_str()+s.size(), m_pathname, codecvt());
      }
    }
```

Comment: The -1 has nothing to do with it.